# Compare a Custom Model index against int array in C# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently developing a site using Code First and Linq to entities.
I Have a custom model called Productos that contains a list of custom models called Especificaciones, wich also contains a custom model called Etiquetas. Etiquetas has a  Property Called EtiquetaId.

This is an example of my models:

```
    public class ObjectProducto
    {
         public IEnumerable<ObjectEspecificaciones> Especificaciones { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjectEspecificaciones
    {
         public IEnumerable<Etiquetas> etiquetas { get; set; }
    }

    public  class Etiquetas
    {
           [Key]
           [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
           public int EtiquetaId { get; set; }
           public string texto { get; set; }
    }
```

I Have an int array filled with values from a view, the array is called MyOptions.

I need to get all the Especificaciones that contains all Etiquetas with EtiquetaId inside MyOptions.

At this point i have retrieved all the Especificaciones that match with ANY of the values inside MyOptions, but i need the Etiquetas Inside Especificaciones that match by ALL MyOptions values.

I have the values from Productos, with all their Especificaciones and all of the Etiquetas inside all of Especificaciones already inside a var called procatm.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
ProductosCatalogo = 
    (from procatm in catm.ProductosCatalogo 
     where procatm.Especificaciones.Any(e => e.etiquetas.Any(et =>                
                                  et.tipo_etiqueta.CompareTo("categoria") != 0 && 
                                  et.tipo_etiqueta.CompareTo("tipo") != 0 && 
                                  MyOptions.Contains(et.EtiquetaId))) 
     select procatm).AsEnumerable()
```

I don't know if i can make something like

```
ProductosCatalogo = 
    (from procatm in catm.ProductosCatalogo 
     where procatm.Especificaciones.Any(e => e.etiquetas.Any(et =>  
                                  et.tipo_etiqueta.CompareTo("categoria") != 0 && 
                                  et.tipo_etiqueta.CompareTo("tipo") != 0 &&
                                  MyOptions.All(...)..... 
     select procatm).AsEnumerable()
```

Can somebody helpme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I din't explained the question far enough..
Only needed to check if an array of Etiquetas was a subset of another array, but all elements in opciones was contained in the tags Ienumerable.

Found the answer :)

Thanks to all the persons that submitted an answer :D

```
public bool IsSubsetof(int[] opciones, IEnumerable<Etiquetas> tags)
{ 
    int[] tagens;
    tagens= new int[tags.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i < tagens.Length; i++)
    {
        tagens[i] = tags.ToArray()[i].EtiquetaId;
    }
    return !opciones.Except(tagens).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are after SelectMany, SelectMany basically flattens out collections, for example two sets like {1, 2} and {3, 4} become {1, 2, 3, 4}

Try this:

```
       ProductosCatalogo = 
           catm.ProductosCatalogo
           .Where(pc => pc.Especificaciones.Any(e => e.etiquetas.Any(et => et.tipo_etiqueta.CompareTo("categoria") != 0 && et.tipo_etiqueta.CompareTo("tipo") != 0 && MyOptions.Contains(et.EtiquetaId))))
           .SelectMany(pc => pc.Especificaciones.SelectMany(et => et.etiquetas));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you just need to replace second `Any` with `All`

```
ProductosCatalogo = 
    (from procatm in catm.ProductosCatalogo 
     where procatm.Especificaciones.Any(e => e.etiquetas.All(et =>
                                 et.tipo_etiqueta.CompareTo("categoria") != 0 &&
                                 et.tipo_etiqueta.CompareTo("tipo") != 0 && 
                                 MyOptions.Contains(et.EtiquetaId))) 
     select procatm).AsEnumerable()
```

In this case all Etiquetas of Especificaciones should present in MyOptions array.